# Double in Mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have created a column with

```
day_endnav double precision
```

When I insert a number: 58.320856084100 in database its stored as 58.3208560841 .
The 2 zeros at the end are removed.

Is there any way to say to mariadb to keep what is entered as it is. Not to roundof or removed zeros at the end?

Comment: The two numbers have the same value so what difference does it make? If you want to display with the trailing zeros, use a function like [`FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

Comment: The requirement from bussiness to return back the value as it is, very though it doesnt make difference.

Comment: So I was wondering if thats possible or not with double datatype

Comment: I think you would need to store it as a string in that case.

Comment: Yeah, string is the solution I went with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two zeros were not "removed".  `DOUBLE` has 53 significant *bits*, which is about 16 significant *decimal* digits.  The *display* of the number probably decided they were irrelevant.  What tool displayed them?

Whether you insert `58.320856084100` or `58.32085608410000000000000`, you will get the same value stored into `DOUBLE`.

Trailing zeros (at least after the decimal point) have no *mathematical* meaning to `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  If *you* have some meaning, then I guess you need to store it as a string, or `DECIMAL`.

`DECIMAL(mm, 12)` will store *and* display `58.320856084100` (if mm >= 14).  However, `DECIMAL` is "fixed-point".  That is, `DECIMAL(20,12)` will always have exactly 12 decimal places, no more, no fewer.

Please state your goal; maybe I have not touched on that point yet.

Comment: I used heidisql to view the data

Comment: I ended up storing as a string, but yeah I didnt like the solution of mine. Thanks for the detail insight. It really helps